# turn.js display option based on window width

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make a flipbook with turn.js which is awesome.
the only problem i have is that i am trying to make it so in mobies it is single page display and in desktops double page display.
it does have the option to choose when creating the flipbook in javascript
display: 'single' or display: 'double'

i managed to achive changing that when you resize the window but with the onresize jwuery event but that makes it so it triggers only when you resize the window but if you dont it is always double page...so when the browser renders the page for mobile it is as defaul double page and not single

let me post my code here
        // Create the flipbook

```
flipbook.turn({

        // Magazine width

        width: 922,

        // Magazine height

        height: 600,

        // Duration in millisecond

        duration: 1000,

        // Enables gradients

        gradients: true,

        // Auto center this flipbook

        autoCenter: true,

        // Elevation from the edge of the flipbook when turning a page

        elevation: 50,

        // The number of pages

        pages: 12,


        // Events

        when: {
            turning: function(event, page, view) {

                var book = $(this),
                currentPage = book.turn('page'),
                pages = book.turn('pages');

                // Update the current URI

                Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

                // Show and hide navigation buttons

                disableControls(page);

            },

            turned: function(event, page, view) {

                disableControls(page);

                $(this).turn('center');

                $('#slider').slider('value', getViewNumber($(this), page));

                if (page==1) {
                    $(this).turn('peel', 'br');
                }

            },

            missing: function (event, pages) {

                // Add pages that aren't in the magazine

                for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                    addPage(pages[i], $(this));

            }
        }

});
    //change from single to double page
      $(window).resize(function(){
         var win = $(this); //this = window
         if (win.width() >= 820) { flipbook.turn('display','double');}
         else {
           flipbook.turn('display','single');
         }
   });
```

i hope someone can help me fix this

Comment: What i need is the browser to check the viewport size before it constructs the flipbook and then set the dispaly option either single or double. is there a way to call an if statement inside the flipbook.turn

Answer (score 2):

To make the flipbook responsive for mobile, you can add the following code, which checks if the user agent of the navigator is mobile or not.

```
function checkMobile() {
 return /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

And then use this in the resize of the window function.

```
if (!checkMobile()) { // not mobile
 $('.flipbook').turn('display', 'double');
}
else {
 $('.flipbook').turn('display', 'single');
}
```

You can use the above snippet after you have initialized the flipbook, to dynamically set the display (double, single) of the flipbook.

Answer (score 0):

so hello everyone again, i managed to figure this out..

i changed the last code part from this

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
var win = $(this); //this = window
if (win.width() >= 820) { flipbook.turn('display','double');}
else {
  flipbook.turn('display','single');
}
});
```

to that

```
 $(window).width(function(){
  var win = $(this); //this = window
  if (win.width() >= 820) { flipbook.turn('display','double');}
  else {
    flipbook.turn('display','single');
  }
});
$(window).resize(function(){
var win = $(this); //this = window
if (win.width() >= 820) { flipbook.turn('display','double');}
else {
  flipbook.turn('display','single');
}
});
```

it works fine both when you refresh the page and when you resize the window. I don't know if this the right way to do it but it seems to work perfectly fine

Comment: This is not working for me. It still displays double on mobile. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

For mobile screens you have to change the screen width
here is tested and working code

```
if(window.innerWidth<768 && window.innerWidth >= 320) {
           $('#flipbook').turn({
            width:430,
            height:650,
            elevation:50,
            inclination:50,
            display: 'single',
            autocenter:true,
            acceleration: true,
            gradients:true,
            zoom:2,// you can change it as you desire
               duration:50,
          });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me on the mobile screen:

```
    $('#flipbook').turn({
                        display: 'single',
                        acceleration: true,
                        gradients: true,
                        elevation:50,
                        when: {
                            turned: function(e, page) {
                                console.log('Current view: ', $(this).turn('view'));
                            }
                        }
                    });
```